# C - Program only doing 1 part of a if else statement

Tags: c, if-statement

Hey so i am trying to create a program that will ask the user for a letter then count how many times that letter appears in a .txt document.
I have the code 99% done its just that whatever if statement i put first is the only one that gives back the correct amount.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define n 61 // Maximum size of file name

FILE* open_file(void) {
  char file_name[n]; FILE* input_file;
  printf("Enter name of the input file: "); scanf("%s", file_name);
  input_file = fopen(file_name, "r");
  while (input_file == NULL) {
    printf("\nERROR: File Not found \"%s\"\n", file_name);
    printf("Re-enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    input_file = fopen(file_name, "r");}
  return input_file;}

void main() {
    char  inputLetter;
    char lowerLetter;
    char upperLetter;
    char chr;
    int upper;
    int lower;
    FILE* input_file = open_file();
    printf("Enter letter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &inputLetter);

    lowerLetter = tolower(inputLetter);
    upperLetter = toupper(inputLetter);
    while(1){
        chr = fgetc(input_file);
        if (chr == EOF){
            break;
        }
        else if(chr ==lowerLetter){
            lower++;
        }
        else if(chr == upperLetter){
            upper++;
        }
    }


    printf(" %c", inputLetter);
    printf(" %c %d ", lowerLetter, lower);
    printf(" %c %d ", upperLetter, upper);
  }
```

When reading a .txt document with 22 lower case e and 2 capital 2 it will print

```
e e 22 E 258
```

If i switch the two if statements with a counter it will print

```
e e 278 E 2
```

What am i doing wrong that it wont count both correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Because you never initialize `upper` or `lower`, try this before `while (1)`

```
upper = 0;
lower = 0;
```

and you don't need that kind of `while (1)` loop which i think is misleading, it would be a lot better if you explicitly use the `break` condition for the loop, i.e.

```
while ((chr = fgetc(input_file)) != EOF)
 {
    if (chr == lowerLetter)
        lower += 1;
    else if (chr == upperLetter)
        upper += 1;
 }
```

Comment: Specifically, you'll want to set `upper` and `lower` to 0

Comment: I originally had the while loop set up like that but was having trouble i was trying different things. but initializing them to 0 fixed my problem. thank you so much! such a easy solution!

Comment: @NicholasChontas check the check mark under the number next to the post :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly your problem (iharob answered that), but it is a bug that may come up if you read a file that contains non-ASCII characters, or if you built your code on an ARM system for example.

The `tolower`, `toupper` and `fgetc` functions do not actually work with `char`s. They work with `int` values in the range `0` to `255`, whereas it is common for a `char` to take the range `-128` through `127`.  <sup>Assuming 8-bit char</sup>.

Passing an out-of-range value to the `to*` or `is*` functions causes undefined behaviour, and the `EOF` test may give false positives or false negatives.

So that part of the code should be:

```
char inputLetter;
int  lowerLetter;
int  upperLetter;
int  chr;

// ...

lowerLetter = tolower( (unsigned char)inputLetter );
upperLetter = toupper( (unsigned char)inputLetter );

// the rest can stay unchanged
```

Comment: I didn't notice that all the variables where `char`'s and the OP expected `fgetc()` to return `EOF` and assigned it to a `char`.